# A nice font style

Tags: fonts

I know there is a command to obtain this style of a font but I cannot recall it. Would you please suggest how to obtain this style?

[image: Here is the font style]

Comment: That would be `\scshape`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called 'small caps' – use `\textsc` or its command version, `\scshape` as appropriate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I like my \textsc{University}.

The {\scshape University} would like
  some more tuition money, please.
\end{document}
```